# How to fit PDF file horizontally in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, iframe

I've been struggling to make pdf fit horizontally dynamically
https://www.modelica.org/events/modelica2011/authors-guide/example-abstract.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0**&view=FitH**

But it does not work in firefox.

You can see demo here though this demo works properly. 
http://jsfiddle.net/raanx/1/

Comment: The jsfiddle does not work "properly" for me; it prompts me for a download. (I'm running Firefox.)

Comment: may be you do not have acrobate reader or any other pdf reader installed on your system.

Comment: I do have readers installed; I don't have a browser plugin however.

Comment: I have a solution in php, and am converting it to javascript for you.

Comment: Do you need a solution that negates a pdf reader being installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, there is no way to resolve such browser specific bugs. The pdf viewer works differently in different browser. I would suggest you to go with Javascript PDF viewers available.

Answer (score 4):

1) embed is old and should not be used anymore to get consistent results.

2) There are multiple ways of going about it (ajax grabbing the file and then rendering it, for example), however, I would eliminate the quirks of involving the browser dependency on a plugin.

To do this 'properly', I would check out https://github.com/andreasgal/pdf.js#readme and look at rendering a pdf in javascript alone. It eliminates the need for a reader installed on the computer, and is the way things will move toward.

3) To handle the horizontal fit, I found that css gave me problems with iframes / pdf combos in a few browsers as of today, and resorted to using old-school width and height as follows. Quirky, but it works in firefox, chrome, IE9, safari, so please do not neg me for browser quirks.  Otherwise I would just use css.

```
<iframe name="myiframe" id="myiframe"  width="100%" height="600" src="viewpdf.php"></iframe>
```

Although not JavaScript, here is some php code that demonstrates how I do it:

viewpdf.php:

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf'); 
header('Accept-Ranges: none');  
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $finalpdf_fn . '"'); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', true);

@readfile($finalpdf_fn);
```

So...in JavaScript, it would look something like:

```
function getXMLHttp() {
  var xmlHttp;
  try {
    //Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } catch(e) {
    //Internet Explorer
    try {
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch(e) {
      try {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch(e) {
        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return xmlHttp;
}        
var oRequest = getXMLHttp();
var sURL = "/tmp/pdf-13319JPL3j7.pdf"; 
oRequest.open("GET",sURL,false);
oRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/pdf");
oRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept-Ranges","none");
oRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename='"+sURL+"'");
oRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding","binary");
oRequest.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control","no-store, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', true");
oRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if( oRequest.readyState == 4 ) {
        if (oRequest.status==200) { 
            document.write (oRequest.responseText);
        }
    }
}
oRequest.send(null)
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Cymbals but I'd tried pdf.js and it does not render complicated pdf files properly (eg. complex tabular data). so i decided to go with pdf-in-iframe solution.

Comment: Ok, I would then use ajax to grab the file, then set the headers properly for a pdf, and then output the file.

Comment: but how would it resolve my issue even after rendering the pdf via ajax? because it is going to be loaded into an iframe in that case too.

Comment: That's fine - the whole point is to avoid the embed which is why you are using ajax to load to it.

Comment: I did not get u. How would you show a pdf file within a page without using iframe or embed or object tag? How ajax comes to the rescue? 
Would like to see the working code too if available?

Comment: clarification: I only said to avoid the embed - the iframe is fine. Essentially, you are loading headers to indicate that it is a pdf, and  then you need to load the contents in the browser. I've got working code in php, but would need to convert it to javascript for you.

Comment: before converting the code into js for me. Try this. Load a pdf using your method in 600X600 iframe and increase the width of the iframe to 1000px or more. Do you see the pdf fit horizontally in chrome/safari? If yes, i would like to look at your php code.

Comment: Confirmed on chrome. Yes, it resizes. If smaller than 100%, it adds a scrollbar to the pdf (assuming greater than one page long). Note: on tablets, scrolling a 100% width pdf-iframe requires two-finger scrolling (not user-friendly).

Comment: I mean do not you see the space in left and right side of the iframe like this http://goo.gl/pw8Rx  - I set the iframe's width to 600px and increase by 100px after clicking a button but if the width exceeds 900px then the pdf does not fit horizontally and it shows the extra space as per explained above.

Comment: Just set it to 100%. If you are referring to the width of the pdf stretching so that there isn't a border...  Chrome will not stretch it however, Firefox and Safari fill the entire width (fit to width)and do not give me a grey area surrounding the pdf at 100%.

Comment: Interesting!!! But it did not work me. I'll grateful to you if u put a small demo on jsfiddle.net. Thanks!

Comment: jsfiddle will not work because ajax won't work cross-domain and it has to load the pdf file locally. :)

Comment: Correction: On jsfiddle, ajax is supported (thru another command) but only on html, jsonp, and json. Not pdf / binary data.

Comment: In that case, you can mail me the code on amit[dot]2006[dot]it[at]gmail[dot]com. Thanks in advance!